# Using a .where IN clause with .includes down and up many nested levels to look up a group of IDs in Rails 3.1

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I would like to filter a list of parent emails addresses by a classroom of students.

Here is a simplification of my models:

```
Class District
 has_many :schools
 has_many :families
 has_many :children, :through => :families
 has_many :parents, :through => :families
 has_many :enrollments, :through => :children
end


Class Enrollments
 belongs_to :child
 belongs_to :classroom
end
```

The email address is associated with the parent record and I would like to filter emails by an array of classroom IDs.

I can get this to work:

```
idees = [49, 50]
current_district = District.first
@emails = current_district.parents.includes(:family => { :children => { :enrollments => {:classroom => { :program => :location }}}}).where("family_id IN (?)", idees)
# Returns families with ID 49 and 50
```

But I cannot get anything like this to work

```
idees = [49, 50]
current_district = District.first
@emails = current_district.parents.includes(:family => { :children => { :enrollments => {:classroom => { :program => :location }}}}).where("family.children.enrollments.classroom_id IN (?)", idees)
# Returns: PGError: ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: family.children.enrollment.classroom_id
```

What am I doing wrong or is there another, better way to write this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line below is the problem.

```
where("family.children.enrollments.classroom_id IN (?)", idees)
```

Change it to :

```
where("enrollments.classroom_id IN (?)", idees)
```

Comment: Thanks. I always find nested queries problematic.

Comment: Welcome. Don't think nested queries, it's just <table_name>.<field_name> :)